# gRPC IFeatureCollection has been disposed. Object name: 'Collection'

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-core-3.1

Using c# gRPC server I have
`IServerStreamWriter<ClientNotification> ClientNotificationStream` to send user notifications

when I'm trying to call `ClientNotificationStream.WriteAsync(parameters)`
I have

````
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'IFeatureCollection has been disposed.
Object name: 'Collection'.'```

IFeatureCollection has been disposed.
Object name: 'Collection'.. Internal Error:  StackTrace:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.ThrowContextDisposed()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.ContextDisposed()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.Fetch[TFeature](TFeature& cached, Func`2 factory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext.get_RequestAborted()
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.HttpContextServerCallContext.get_CancellationTokenCore()
   at Grpc.Core.ServerCallContext.get_CancellationToken()
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.HttpContextStreamWriter`1.WriteAsync(TResponse message)
````

Comment: I suspect the connection never completed and then got disposed.  So this is a connection issue (unless you never created the object).

Comment: Connection created by gRPC `service Connector{
 rpc Start(ConnectorRequest) returns (stream ClientNotification);
}` and user get first message on calling Start method. Error occures on calling WriteAsync next time.

Comment: Do you have a remote or local client?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/clients/manage/client-notification

Comment: @jdweng That is my local development server. Separate gRPC server and test gRPC client. Thay both runs on my my local server.

Comment: I added `deadline:DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)`. After it I get  `Error: The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed.. Internal Error:  StackTrace:    at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
   at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.get_Token()
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.ServerCallDeadlineManager.get_CancellationToken()
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.HttpContextServerCallContext.get_CancellationTokenCore()
   at Grpc.Core.ServerCallContext.get_CancellationToken()
   `

Comment: Do you have same account on both local and remote machines (Like a Group Policy Account)?  Did  you read the "End Point Protection" link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224049/discussion-between-valery-yegorov-and-jdweng).

Comment: @ValeryYegorov how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

ClientNotificationStream was disposed when I need to do WriteAsync().To fix it I add

`WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { context.CancellationToken.WaitHandle });`

`context` is `ServerCallContext`